# How to give different role permissions to same url with different request method types in spring boot secuirty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, authorization

I am using spring boot security to authenticate and authorize my rest http apis. 
I see that we can set authorization setttings like this

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
//              .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/health_check/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/registration").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/user/login","/user/logout").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN","MANAGER")
                .antMatchers("/admin/*").fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().csrf().disable();

        }

    }
```

I wanted to  know how to give different permission to different urls which differ in request methods?

Eg:
if i have to two urls like

```
// GET /api/account/{id}
// POST /api/account/{id}
// PUT /api/account/{id}
```

i wish to give only admin acces to PUT and user access to GET and both user and admin access to POST.. how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can pass request method in `antMatchers`.

Try with this:

```
            http
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/account/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/account/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/account/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@PreAuthorize` annotation on controller's methods:

```
@GetMapping("/api/account/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasAutority('readAccountById')")
public Account getAccount(@PathVariable Integer id){
   ...
}
```

It works with Spring security context, and you can check user roles, authorities and many more.

For reference have a look at this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security